# Compare indexes in two databases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

When updating our clients' software and databases, we're comparing their database to our development database, to be sure that no tables are missing and that all tables look the same.

It's an easy job doing this because of the information stored in `[DB].Information_Schema.Columns`.

Now, we want to compare all the indexes in the client database to our development database, but I have no idea where to look to do a comparison. So, where do I start looking?

**Edit:**

I would love a TSQL solution rather than getting more software to do the job. And yes, I know that RedGate has some great solutions, but I'm not willing to pay for something I can do for free. This question is not only to get the job done, but to get even more knowledge about SQL Server and learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with a comparison tool like the Microsoft SSDT (free - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx ), or Redgate's SQL Compare, rather than doing this manually.

Alternately, you can look at `sysindexes`

Comment: sysindexes are great! Thanks. I'll accept the answer when I can (in 3min).

Answer (score 5):

The script which show you indexes in your Microsoft SQL server database is:

```
USE [database name];

SELECT
     t.name tableName,
     ind.name indexName,
     col.name columnName,
     key_ordinal columnOrder
FROM
     sys.indexes ind
INNER JOIN
     sys.index_columns ic ON  ind.object_id = ic.object_id and ind.index_id = ic.index_id
INNER JOIN
     sys.columns col ON ic.object_id = col.object_id and ic.column_id = col.column_id
INNER JOIN
     sys.tables t ON ind.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE
     ind.is_primary_key = 0
     AND ind.is_unique = 0
     AND ind.is_unique_constraint = 0
     AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
ORDER BY
     t.name, ind.name, ind.index_id, ic.index_column_id
```

I write script which use query above and can help compare indexes in two databases.
https://github.com/dlevsha/compalex

> Compalex is a lightweight script to compare two database schemas. It
>   supports MySQL, MS SQL Server and PostgreSQL.

Screenshot (compare keys):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try with this free utility [SQL Server Database Comparison Tool](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/205011/SQL-Server-Database-Comparison-Tool).

Sometimes we have some problems on big databases, but for the rest it does it job.

Hope it can help